# Div with 100% height having no browser scrollbars

Tags: html, css, jquery-ui

I have a panel having divs in the following order

```
<div id="portlet" class="ui-widget-content">
     <div id="header" class="ui-widget-header"> ....</div>
     <div id="content"> ... </div>
</div>
```

My content gets the scrollbar if the content overflows. I have a maximise button to maximise the panel. So when I maximise the panel I add the following css class.

```
.maximise {
    position: absolute !important;
    width: 100% !important;
    height: 100% !important;
    left: 0px !important;
    top: 0px !important;
    z-index: 1 !important;
 }
```

But then I get the browsers scrollbar and the contents scrollbar as well.
Please help!!!
Thank you in advance.

Comment: GAH! What are all those !imporant statements doing there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is usually because of padding, border or margin, so try setting these to `0` first.

Widths and heights are both calculated **before** padding and border is applied. If this is a percentage, the overall width of your div would be 100% of the page + any padding or border.

You can tell the browser to calculate these percentages widths **after** padding and border is applied using the [`box-sizing`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/box-sizing) CSS property.

```
.maximise { box-sizing: border-box; }
```

However this doesn't work in all browsers. You may need the vendor-specific properties too.

Comment: You're welcome :) Check Firefox! Firefox was always the one I remember I had to use the vendor-specific property: `-moz-box-sizing`.

Comment: Its quite buggy in IE 9. Its maximising properly..but then after restore my content is getting disappeared.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
overflow-x:hidden; 
overflow-y:hidden;
```

to hide the scrollbars.

Comment: What about simply `overflow:hidden` instead?

Comment: It doesn't always hide the scrollbars.